# Extract CSV file from Github library with python

Tags: python, csv, github, export, extract

I'm looking to pull a specific file from a  github repo and load into a dictionary in python and then write the file back to a specific folder in the github repo.

Suppose, my folder structure is:

Github Repo > files > rawfiles > test.txt

Github Repo > files > output > output.txt

How would I extract one file from Github and then write it back to Github? Below is what I have created, but the output seems to be including all the HTML tags.

```
import csv
import urllib
url = 'GithubRepo/rawfiles/test.txt'
webpage = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = []
datareader = csv.reader(webpage)
    for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)
```

print data

Comment: Do you know how Git works (distributed model, commits and commit messages, remotes, etc.)?

Comment: If you are shure that you want to use Git(hub) you can use the API https://developer.github.com/v3/git/ or git itself.

Comment: did you try to urlopen this link instead? `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/your_repo..`

Answer (score 1):

you should try to .read() the url open request.

lets say you want to parse `https://github.com/codeforamerica/ohana-api/blob/master/data/sample-csv/addresses.csv`

so you change the appendinx to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`

and writing the following code

```
import urllib.request as request
import csv
r = request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/ohana-api/master/data/sample-csv/addresses.csv').read().decode('utf8').split("\n")
reader = csv.reader(r)
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```